# Salesforce Formula criteria check on two different values

Tags: formula, process-builder

For a process builder criteria, I have a formula that I wish to expand with a check whether `AND(ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Email: X@X.com")` is used, and otherwise the criteria check should continue as below.

How can I incorporate the value check on X@X.com?

My formula looks like:

```
AND( ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Email: X@X.com")
```

I added the part above, that doesn't seem to work. The part below works when I remove the part above

```
OR( [Case].RecordType.DeveloperName = "X_Cases",
    OR( ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Email: Y@Y.com"),
        AND( ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Web"),
            ISPICKVAL([Case].Web_to_Case_Source__c, "Y")
        ),
        AND(
            OR( ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "A"),
                ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "B"),
                ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "C")
            ),
            NOT(ISBLANK([Case].SourceId)),
            [Case].Source:SocialPost.PostTags = "Y"
        ),
        AND( ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Y"),
            ISPICKVAL([Case].Country__c, "Y")
        ),
        AND( NOT(ISBLANK([Case].Y__c)),
            ISPICKVAL([Case].Origin, "Y"),
            [Case].Y__Original_Interaction__c.Y__Country_Code__c = "Y"
        )
    )
)
```